# Logout script in selenium webdriver chrome

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I'm new in selenium.

I logged into Facebook through selenium webdriver script but now i want to logout. Please help me with the script.

eg:

```
   public class AJ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://facebook.com");
        WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
        element.sendKeys("ajaykumar0891@yahoo.com");
        element=driver.findElement(By.name("pass"));
        element.sendKeys("devilhacker");

        element.submit();

       }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried something like finding out the id or xpath of the logout button?

Comment: it does not show any id?  Please check this script.                         public class AJ {

 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 

  
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
     driver.get("http://facebook.com");
     WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
     element.sendKeys("ajaykumar0891@yahoo.com");
     element=driver.findElement(By.name("pass"));
     element.sendKeys("devilhacker");
     
     element.submit();

Comment: if you are using firefox browser with firebug addon, right click on the drop down arrow in the facebook home page at the top right corner and click `inspect element with firebug` and check the html code. if id is not available, you can use xpath, css, name etc. after clicking on the drop down, you can repeat the same thing for logout option in the drop down. u need to find out id/name/xpath/css for the same and then perform click().

Answer (score 0):

I haven't executed the below code, but I guess this should work.

```
WebElement userMenuPullDown = driver.findElement(By.id("navAccountLink"));
userMenuPullDown.click();

WebElement logoutOption = driver.findElement(By.id("logout_form"));
logoutOption.click();
```

Comment: Have you tried this way? I tried and it was not work with current Facebook.